# Finding manpages with emacs on windows

Tags: man

I am using Emacs 26.1 on Windows. I am reading manpages using (man). When I invoke (man) ivy jumps in and offeres me the selection of available manpages. This selection is for some reason empty (no manpages are offered). If I enter the name of a manpage that I know it exists the manpage is shown.

If I invoke (woman) on the other hand ivy shows me a nice list of available manpages.

As I really only use (man) to read manpages I wonder if there is way to have ivy offer me completion when chosing a manpage?

I went through the customization group for "man" to see if there is any hint. I also did invoke a search engine in an un-motivated way.

EDIT: Doing: "emacs -Q", invoke man, hit tab does not offer any available manpages while on ther other hand doing "emacs -Q", invoke woman, hit tab does offer lots of manpages.

Comment: If you eliminate `ivy` from the equation, does `man` give you completion options?  (i.e. Is the problem with `M-x man` or with `ivy` ?)

Comment: see EDIT above, please.